# Payara Micro ConfigProperty "payara.instance.https.port" not working correctly

Tags: payara, payara-micro

Currently I use `payara-micro-4.1.2.174` and `microprofile-config-api.version 1.2.1` and injected follow:

but always get the http Port and not the https port.

```
"@Inject @ConfigProperty(name="payara.instance.https.port") int httpsPort;"
```

Why am I getting the http port and not the https port?

Answer (score 1):

Payara Micro does not start an SSL port by default, you need to specify it on the command line with `--sslport`. [Auto binding is also supported with the `--autobindssl` option](https://docs.payara.fish/documentation/payara-micro/port-autobinding.html).

Once the SSL port is present, then the `@ConfigProperty` injection should work, if not, then [that would be a bug to be raised on GitHub](https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues).

Comment: i did start with options --port 9190 --sslport 9191

Comment: In that case, this is very likely to be a bug and should be raised at https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues